# Jquery simple photo manager demo - recycle trash completely

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using the Jquery's simple photo manager just as it is and it's working properly.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/photo-manager.html

All I need is the possibility to recycle all the elements from the trash by a single click.
Sounds simple but I couldn't get it so far. Ok, I'm a newbie to Jquery.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I added a link "Recycle all" and the trigger('click') to the event delegation. Nothing happens on the "Recycle all" link but the images are recycled by clicking on the images "recycle image".Additionally image four gets a multiple "Delete image" link in the gallery after recycling!?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#trash .ui-icon-refresh').trigger('click');`

In your setup at http://romtec-online.com/photo-manager.html, you could write the following line to enable the 'Recycle all' button:

```
$('.ui-icon-recycle-all').click(function() {
    $('#trash .ui-icon-refresh').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not sure how to implement this. Either nothing happens or I receive a "too much recursion" error.

Comment: I tried it on the jQuery UI demo through the Firebug console - do you have a link to your setup?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real setup, but you can see what I did under the following address:

http://romtec-online.com/photo-manager.html

Sorry, lost my login somehow...

Comment: You've added the function to the recycle link on the items - if you want to enable it for the "recycle all" button, see my updated answer. And just a side-note, it is better to add this information to your question rather than posting it as an answer...

Comment: Perfect! it's working, thank you very much!
(as I mentioned before I lost my login somehow, so I have to post it this way, sorry).